# Updating SQLite database in background thread on Android

Tags: android, database, multithreading, android-cursoradapter

I'm using a custom CursorAdapter to display data stored in a database. The data is pulled from a server, parsed, and inserted into the database in a separate thread. Because I don't want to keep around any old data, I delete all rows from the table, then insert each row as I parse the information in the server response. If I scroll around in the ListActivity, I sometimes get a crash, apparently, when the table is cleared, and CursorAdapter getView or bindView are trying to query the cursor.

It is NOT my custom CursorAdapter which fails, I've already handled the RuntimeException that can happen when I use getInt() or getString().

From what I've read, serialization of queries is dependent on how you use SQLiteOpenHelpers.
I've created a custom SQLiteOpenHelper, similar to the notepad example in the Android demos.

When I update my db I use the following code snippet:

```
ContentResolver cr = ctx.getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
String response = _getUrlResponse(url);
cr.delete(tableName);
values.put(parseString(response));
cr.insert(tableName, values);
```

Is there a better way to perform the db operations than by using a ContentResolver?

The logcat is:

```
03-07 15:35:07.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15826): java.lang.IllegalStateException: couldn't move cursor to position 17
03-07 15:35:07.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15826):     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:178)
03-07 15:35:07.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15826):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1460)
03-07 15:35:07.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15826):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1809)
03-07 15:35:07.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15826):     at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:764)
03-07 15:35:07.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15826):     at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:710)
03-07 15:35:07.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15826):     at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:3421)
03-07 15:35:07.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15826):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:2301)
03-07 15:35:07.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15826):     at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:3621)
03-07 15:35:07.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15826):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3823)
03-07 15:35:07.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15826):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:897)
03-07 15:35:07.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15826):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
03-07 15:35:07.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15826):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
03-07 15:35:07.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15826):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:936)
03-07 15:35:07.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15826):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1723)
03-07 15:35:07.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15826):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1129)
03-07 15:35:07.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15826):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2086)
03-07 15:35:07.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15826):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1707)
03-07 15:35:07.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15826):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1785)
03-07 15:35:07.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15826):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-07 15:35:07.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15826):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-07 15:35:07.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15826):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-07 15:35:07.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15826):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 15:35:07.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15826):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-07 15:35:07.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15826):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
03-07 15:35:07.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15826):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
03-07 15:35:07.351: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(15826):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: might be good to post the Cursor code anyway

Comment: I should have said, the only functions of CursorAdapter that I am overriding are newView() and bindView(). As to the getCount() suggestion, perhaps I can do something like this:

`@Override
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  try {
   return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
  } catch (RuntimeException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   super.getCursor().requery();
   return newView(parent.getContext(), super.getCursor(), parent);
  }
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Are you possibly not updating your `getCount()` value as the data in your `Cursor` changes? It seems like it is trying to move to a row that no longer exists.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue. I solved it by **removing** a line I had in my code:

```
mCursorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```